# Is there a reason why it isn't sensing my input.getaxis

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I even set up public variables to see if was getting any input, and it isn't. I even copied and pasted the names directly from the project settings page.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class vehicle : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector3 thrusterInput;
    public float rotationSpeed = 10f;
    public float rotSmoothSpeed = 10f;
    private Quaternion smoothedRot = Quaternion.identity;
    private Quaternion targetRot;
    Body[] bodies;
    public Rigidbody rigidbody;
    public float thrustStrength = 10f;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        bodies = FindObjectsOfType<Body>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        foreach(Body body in bodies)
        {
            float sqrDst = (body.transform.position - transform.position).sqrMagnitude;
            Vector3 forceDir = (body.transform.position - transform.position).normalized;
            Vector3 acceleration = forceDir * Universe.gravitationalConstant * body.rigid.mass / sqrDst;
            rigidbody.AddForce(acceleration, ForceMode.Acceleration);
        }

        Vector3 thrustDir = transform.TransformVector(thrusterInput);
        rigidbody.AddForce(thrustDir * thrustStrength, ForceMode.Acceleration);
        rigidbody.MoveRotation(smoothedRot);
    }

    void HandleMovement()
    {
        float thrustInputX = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float thrustInputY = Input.GetAxis("Ascent");
        float thrustInputZ = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        thrusterInput = new Vector3(thrustInputX, thrustInputY, thrustInputZ);

        float yawInput = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * rotationSpeed;
        float pitchInput = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * rotationSpeed;
        float rollInput = Input.GetAxis("Roll") * rotationSpeed;

        Quaternion yaw = Quaternion.AngleAxis(yawInput, transform.up);
        Quaternion pitch = Quaternion.AngleAxis(pitchInput, transform.right);
        Quaternion roll = Quaternion.AngleAxis(rollInput, transform.forward);

        targetRot = yaw * pitch * roll * targetRot;
        smoothedRot = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, targetRot, Time.deltaTime * rotSmoothSpeed);
    }
}
```

Sorry if the indents are all messed up, stackoverflow wasn't letting me use tab for some reason.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You can check https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for Editing in general and for tabs maybe this helps https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255953/why-does-the-tab-key-not-work-while-writing-questions-answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `HandleMovement()` is not called from anywhere. You need to put it in `Update()`

Comment: Thanks, feels like every time a have an error I can't figure out, its something stupid like this lol